# Powershell Core to read file metadata

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

I need a way to read file metadata using Powershell Core 7.x on macOS.

In a MS Windows environment, I was able to use `Shell.Application` COM object and `getDetailsOf()` method to retrieve the information.  However, I can't find this option in PowerShell Core on macOS.

I found someone who used external commands (I guess some are written in python) in PowerShell core to retrieve the information, but I would like to do that using PowerShell only.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Powershell core?

Thanks

Comment: Which metadata are you looking for? There are plenty of different types of metadata. There is file system metadata, like file size, name, timestamps; technical metadata of certain file types; standardized external metadata like EXIF, XMP, IPTC... Can you post an example of the metadata inside your windows environment?

Comment: Hi Thomas.  I am looking at EXIF, GPS, IPTC, mp3tag at the moment.

Comment: Then I am even more curious on how you did that with plain PowerShell on Windows. I am not aware of any built-in functions for this purpose. You normally need external tools like the [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) or [exiv2](https://www.exiv2.org/).

Comment: Hi Thomas.  Thanks for your suggestions.  exiftool is one of the external programs that is used to extract the information and then I parse the result in Powershell.  In Windows environment, this can be archived by creating an COM object of shell.application or/and WIA, and then parse the COM object for the attributes

Comment: Barry I am facing the same issue! I want to write a multiplatform script, but I don't know how to get EXIF data on MacOS without running external tools

Comment: Hi Riccardo,  I ended up using external tools.... the only method I found that worked without using external external tools was parsing COM object, which only works on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a "Shell.Application COM object" to execute an external tool, you can just use the `Start-Process` cmdlet and capture the output of this process:

```powershell
$f = New-TemporaryFile
Start-Process exiftool -ArgumentList "myImage.jpg" -RedirectStandardOutput $f.FullName -Wait
$result = Get-Content -Path $f.FullName
Remove-Item -Path $f.FullName

# Now, the result of the exiftool is available in $result for further processing
```

Comment: I have currently no macOS available for testing, but `Start-Process` is the common way to execute external tools and I am quite confident that it will work.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  I did use external programs (e.g. exiftool) to retrieve the information and parse the result, but this is not what I wanted as I found using an external program was a lot slower than the COM object method that I use in MS Windows environment.  This is why I am looking for a pure Powershell core method to retrieve the information.  Just for sharing.  I currently needed to copy files to a NAS where it is accessible by both the mac and the Windows machine, and then I run the Powershell from Windows to generate the result for >50k files.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: PowerShell has no built-in functionality to exrtact EXIF, IPTC or XMP metadata. And I highly doubt that PowerShell will be faster than any compiled executable. [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) has its origin in Perl. If that's too slow for you, have a look at [exiv2](https://www.exiv2.org/), it is programmed in C++. This might be faster than the ExifTool (not tested though). Both tools are available for Windows, Linux and macOS. Every well written and natively executed binary will most probably be faster than any scripting language.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  As I mentioned, I have a workaround but that's time consuming and I need to do this from time to time so I am looking for a faster script.  I have no doubt exiftool is a fast tool but unfortunately calling it from Powershell which I believe it needs to spawn another process is slow. The MS Windows that I run is a slow VM but it still finishes a lot quicker than my mac which is much powerful in terms of hardware.

Comment: In case anyone is interested how a COM object in MS Windows environment can be used to extract metadata.  This is an example that uses WIA. 

$image = New-Object -ComObject WIA.ImageFile
$image.LoadFile($filename)
$image.Width

Comment: Thx for sharing. As far as I can tell, [`ImageFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-imagefile) covers only technical metadata (metadata defined by the format specification). How did you get EXIF data - especially GPS data - with that?

Comment: The latitude and longtitude can be retrieved using $image.Properties.Item('2').value and $image.properties.item('4').value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226092/discussion-between-barry-chum-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0):

`Shell.Application` is part of Win32, it's literally the [Windows shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-entry)!

So when you load it via COM, you're basically telling Powershell do the same function the shell uses for the UI details tab, GetDetailsof. COM is just how you're communicating to the process, to tell it to run a particular method.

So could this work on Powershell Core? Only if you're running Powershell Core on a Windows system. That is because the dependency is a method provided by the platform.   You have no other choice than to read the metadata yourself, via another library.

You might want to check out, [metadata-extractor-dotnet](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet)

Something like that is what you'd need to implement the functionality. I don't have experiance using that lib myself, but at least it might provide a good jump off point for further research.

Comment: Hi Becker, exactly.  Thats why i posted to see if anyone knows a comparable method as the one from Shell.Application.  Looks like there isn’t.  Thanks

Comment: @BarryChum GetDetailsof is checking for multiple different formats of metadata, then looking for corresponding keys that are found when a file with whatever form of metadata is being examined. Then it somehow prefers a key from one format of metadata over another. I wouldn't be shocked if it's checking for JFIF, EXIF, IPTC and XMP.

Comment: I know of some libraries that check for a few formats of metadata, but you'd likely still need to code that logic to weigh/prioritize whichever [format][key]'s from the results.

Comment: @BarryChum I added some more info to my answer.